# cURL returning empty string

Tags: php, html, json, curl, web

Hey am I missing a curl_opt or something? This code was working yesterday and now it doesnt work. It is suppose to return a json string but instead returns empty string.

```
<?php
session_start();

$UCID=$_POST['UCID'];
$Pass=$_POST['Pass'];
$credentials=array("Username"=>$UCID, "Password"=>$Pass);
$post_field_string = http_build_query($credentials, '', '&');






$url1="https://web.njit.edu/~vm276/connect.php";
//$url1="https://www.njit.edu/cp/login.php";
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTPS);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_field_string);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json=json_decode($result);
    echo $json->result;
?>
```

Comment: problem with https://www.njit.edu/cp/login.php ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about errors by adding to your code:

```
$result= curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);

if(200 == $httpCode) {
  //...
}
else {
 echo "httpCode: ".$httpCode."\n";
 var_dump($error);
 exit();
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php